# Refer to a nested class in parent class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, static, nested

I'm trying to create a nested class mostly because the nested classes only need to be used inside the parent. I've tried the following ...

```
class Foo {
  static Bar = class {}

  myBar: Foo.Bar // This gives "'Foo' refers to a type but is being used as a namespace here"
}

const bar = new Foo.Bar() // This is OK
```

... but as the comment says, this doesn't work when used as a type inside the parent. Is there a correct way to reference that I am missing?

I'm using Typescript 4.1.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bear with me, because the type for this is more complicated than you might think.

The name `Foo` refers to the class variable itself and also to the type for an *instance* of the `Foo` class.  Calling `new Foo.Bar()` is fine because you accessing `.Bar` on the *variable* `Foo`.  You cannot access `.Bar` on the *type* Foo because that is not how you access properties in typescript.  Dot notation is used only for namespaces, which is why you get the error "'Foo' refers to a type but is being used as a namespace here".

The syntax for accessing properties is `Foo['Bar']`.  But this doesn't work either because the type `Foo` refers to an *instance* of the class rather than to the class itself.  `Bar` is a `static` property, so it does not exist on the instance.  As [explained here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions), we need to use `typeof Foo` to get the type for the *class constructor* `Foo`.

So now we try `(typeof Foo)['Bar']` and we are almost there, except that this returns the type for the *class constructor* of `Bar` and we (presumably) want the type for an *instance*. So finally we arrive at the type:

```
InstanceType<(typeof Foo)['Bar']>
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/DWKz8m)

Comment: Version with a bit less parentheses `InstanceType<typeof Foo.Bar>` 